# Should I use volatile for ISRs in C++? (not C)

Tags: c++, c, volatile, isr

I commonly see that variables which are accessed by ISRs should be marked as `volatile`. I can understand this would be the case in pure C, where the compiler isn't aware of other threads.
Is this still the case in C++, where the compiler understands that non-local variables can be accessed by other threads?

If `volatile` is needed, what makes the ISR different from just any other thread?

Comment: Have a read of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv Specifically _"...This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution..."_ ie the compiler must not optimise out the volatile access but the hardware is not required to synchronise volatile access (required to avoid UB with threads).

Comment: @RichardCritten Volatile isn't used for the purpose of preventing race conditions.

Comment: What are you asking about - ISRs or threads?

Comment: Duplicate on EE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102. There's no difference between C and C++.

Comment: @molbdnilo It's pretty much the same thing as far as volatile is concerned. What matters is if the compiler understands that a certain callback function might be called from other sources than the code it is compiling.

Comment: @Lundin I never said it was.

Comment: @RichardCritten You brought up an irrelevant argument about race conditions. That's not the issue here, but incorrect code optimization due to the compiler not realizing that a callback is called.

Comment: I was using *a lot* of `volatile` keywords when I was programming for printer software, at least 10 years ago. This was in C++98. But now, with the evolution of the language and optimizing compilers, I have the impression that *nearly every time we are tempted to use `volatile`, a `std::atomic<>` is in fact what is needed*. I think the only legitimate use of `volatile` keyword today is to access memory mapped hardware registers. For variables in ISR, written by software, please use `std::atomic`.

Comment: @prapin It's all explained in the link I posted. The separate issues of optimizations and race conditions.

Comment: @Lundin Looking at the example I still don't quite understand what difference it makes whether `ADC0_interrupt` is an interrupt handler or not. If the compilation-unit knows that it's an exported function which could be called at any time from any thread, then surely it can't optimize away `adc_data` in `adc_stuff`?

Comment: @prapin this was my understanding too. The value in memory can change in ways the compiler doesn't know about. I've also managed to hack an example where you can use known memory-layouts etc to get a pointer to a variable without the compiler knowing; in that case, volatile can fix things too.

Comment: @RichardCritten That quote looks like has the answer, but I'm trying to understand more about why. If ThreadA is executing some code, it can be suspended after any instruction, and then another ISR/thread can start, right? If the optimized code expects other threads to execute, why does it not expect ISRs? And why does it make a difference what initially caused the CPU to execute the code?

Comment: @fizzybones Historically, embedded systems compilers have been notoriously bad at this. Been a long while since I encountered this particular bug outside old legacy code bases. Basically a compiler must recognize that it's own interrupt keyword means that access to any variable accessed by that interrupt may not get optimized out. The only way to tell is to disassemble.

Comment: Also, this sad state of affairs is largely the C standard committee's fault for not adding `interrupt` and `asm` as standardized keyword. One would think the assumption that C might be executed on computers isn't that far-fetched, since approximately 99.99% of all C programs ever written in the past 50 years or so have been written for the purpose to be executed on computers... Even C++ has standardized `asm`.